# How Can I Put The Current Date In Text Widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello everyone I'm beginner in flutter..

I'm building an Alarm app using dart and flutter but when I try to put the current date in the text widget I have an error

```
A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.

Failed assertion: line 370 pos 10: 'data != null'
```

and this my code

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {


String greetingMessage() {
var timeNow = DateTime.now().hour;

if (timeNow <= 11.59) {
  return 'Good Morning';
} else if (timeNow > 12 && timeNow <= 16) {
  return 'Good Afternoon';
} else if (timeNow > 16 && timeNow < 20) {
  return 'Good Evening';
} else {
  return 'Good Night';
}

String finalDate = '';



getCurrentDate() {
var date = DateTime.now().toString();

var dateParse = DateTime.parse(date);

var formattedDate = "${dateParse.day}-${dateParse.month}-${dateParse.year}";

setState(() {
  finalDate = formattedDate.toString();
});



Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30, bottom: 18),
                child: Text(
                  greetingMessage(),
                  style:
                      TextStyle(fontSize: 25, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
              ),
              Text(
                getCurrentDate(),
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.black54),
```

if anyone can help me I appreciate your effort
thanks.

Comment: Have you checked my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not formatted and You had written **Padding** and **TextField** Widget without having **Column** or that type of widget which can display code in vertically.

Here is full working code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30, bottom: 18),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Text(
            greetingMessage(),
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
          Text(getCurrentDate(),
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.cyan))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  String greetingMessage() {
    var timeNow = DateTime.now().hour;

    if (timeNow <= 11.59) {
      return 'Good Morning';
    } else if (timeNow > 12 && timeNow <= 16) {
      return 'Good Afternoon';
    } else if (timeNow > 16 && timeNow < 20) {
      return 'Good Evening';
    } else {
      return 'Good Night';
    }
  }

  String getCurrentDate() {
    var date = DateTime.now().toString();

    var dateParse = DateTime.parse(date);

    var formattedDate = "${dateParse.day}-${dateParse.month}-${dateParse.year}";
    return formattedDate.toString();
  }
}
```

Output:

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To Show the `Date` in `Text` widget, You Need to return the `Date` from the `getCurrentDate()` method, While Accessing your `getCurrentDate()` method in `Text` Widget otherwise it will return a `null` and Show an ***error***.

**In Simple Words** : *Just add a return statement to your method and return your formattedDate.*

```
getCurrentDate() {
   var date = DateTime.now().toString();

   var dateParse = DateTime.parse(date);

   var formattedDate = "${dateParse.day}-${dateParse.month}-${dateParse.year}";

   return formattedDate;
}
```